# Is there a way to store a logical operator in a Bash script variable

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a need to make logical operators (&&, ||) configurable in a Bash script.  In other words I would like to read a literal representing the operator from a config file and use it in the script.

An example expression would be:

```
if [ -n $var1 ] $LOP [ -n $var2]
```

where

```
$LOP = '&&' or '||' as read from the config file.
```

Is this even possible ?  Using the expression as I have shown results in an error.

Comment: that seems very error prone... suggest you rethink

Comment: You should use double quotes around the variables, especially with `-n` and `-z` (so `[ -n "$var1" ]`).  You might be able to do it with `eval`, but I'd be very worried about trying to do so.  Using `eval` is powerful but fiendishly tricky and very susceptible to security problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this inside the `[` command:

```
if [ -n "$var1" "$LOP" -n "$var2" ]
```

***But*** you need to use `-a` for "and" (`&&`) and `-o` for "or" (`||`).

It is vitally important the you quote variable expansions when using `[`. If you don't quote the expansion and the variable is empty or undefined, the test expression will have incorrect syntax.  For example, if `$var1` is undefined,  `[ -n $var1; ]` will be evaluated as `[ -n ]` which is always true.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a case statement:

```
case $LOP in
  ('&&' | 'and')
    if [ -n "$var1" -a -n "$var2" ]; then ...; fi
    ;;
  ('||' | 'or')
    if [ -n "$var1" -o -n "$var2" ]; then ...; fi
    ;;
  (*)
    printf '%s: invalid operator: "%s"\n' "${0##*/}" "$LOP" >&2
    ;;
esac
```

Note how easy this is to extend and also accept more readable values in `$LOP`. It's also portable, since it does not rely on bashisms.

Comment: This is what I needed for solving my problem.  I can also see how I can extend this more fully as an expression evaluator.

Comment: @crayguy Wonderful; the next step on Stackoverflow is to upvote the helpful answers (you can upvote more than one answer) and/or *accept* the one that solved your problem best (you may even change your mind later on which answer you consider best).

Answer (score 0):

If your usecase allows it, you can read the whole conditions into some variable and use the `eval` to evaluate, for example:

```
var1=2
var2=42

while read -r cond
do
    eval "[[ $cond ]]" && { echo "$cond true"; } || { echo "$cond false"; }

done < <(sed '/^[ \t]*#/d;/^[ \t]*$/d' <<'EOF'
#complex tests
-n $var1 && -z $var2
$var1 == 1 || $var2 == 42

#arithmetics
$(($var2 + $var1)) < 44
$(($var2 + $var1)) < 45

#even commands
$(date +%Y) < 2014
EOF
)
```

which produces

```
-n $var1 && -z $var2 false
$var1 == 1 || $var2 == 42 true
$(($var2 + $var1)) < 44 false
$(($var2 + $var1)) < 45 true
$(date +%Y) < 2014 false
```

The `eval` is powerfull but also it is **VERY DANGEROUS**. Use it **only** if you can abosolutely trust in the content of the evaled variable.